# Unity3d Facebook SDK "Nearby" message

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I am not sure if the title of my post is right, spare me if it is wrong :)

I am using the latest facebook sdk with unity (Ver 4.2). When i call a fb.api request, i get the message "Nearby" whenever some facebook stuff is loading.

Scenario.

1. A share on fb/ connect with fb/ invite friends function, loads facebook.
2. At this point, there is a waiting dialog. Weirdly enough this waiting shows "Nearby" rather than waiting/loading. And i could not find any option to configure this.

I looked high and low, but could not find a place where i could configure the default waiting message. Any suggestions?

Comment: The same problem... Looking to disable that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify Unity/Assets/Plugin/Android/res/value/strings.xml - modify `<string name="com_facebook_nearby">nearby</string>` entity. But I think it is not a solution. I guess that there is some kind of logic with place picking in the Unity Facebook SDK while login flow. But unfortunately I have not figure out it yet

Comment: That works. But as you said yourself it is not a solution, and probably a bug from the SDK itself.
Thanks for pointing me to the right file, did'nt think it could be in android section, thought the SDK was a global mobile SDK.

Comment: There is no progress dialog in iOS. It has implementation via fast-app-switch

Comment: Yeah i have realized that once i started implementing it on IOS. When i asked the question i was only curious :). Thanks Subtle Fox